# Adding catagory labels on a stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I am have a made a `geom_col()` chart in ggplot2 for which I would like to add labels on the bars, but only one per stacked bar.
This is what my chart looks like without the labels:

```
gI <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = Category, y=csum, x= tijdas)) +
  geom_col()
plot(gI)
```

[image]

And now comes the tricky part. Every stacked bar has is a specific Meeting_type and I would like to add this to the plot. I have tried adding

```
geom_text(aes(label = Meeting_Type), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

But this resulted in a label for every category within each bar (so a lot of text):
[image]

I would like only one label per (stacked) bar that indicates the Meeting_type. Preferably in a readable place.

Comment: To get rid of the duplicated labels move `fill = Category` as local aes into `geom_col`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to know the best approach without seeing your data, but it's possible that substituting `geom_text` for `stat_summary` would be a good way of summing each column to get the position of the label:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_col() +
  stat_summary(aes(label = factor(cyl), fill = NULL),
               fun = sum, 
               geom = "text", vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As I say, may need a different function for your data - if this isn't a solution then do post a sample using `dput` and we'll see if we can make it work for your data.

Comment: Glad it helped! I've used several bad ways of trying to solve this problem in the past, but the `stat_summary` function that I've just recently started getting used to is really good for tidying/shortening code.